# I live in Maryland and work in Virginia. Do I need to file multiple state tax returns?

Tags: united-states, taxes, state-income-tax, maryland, virginia

I live in Maryland and commute everyday to Virginia for my job. I do not have any rental property in Virginia. Do I need to file multiple state taxes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maryland , Virginia, and Washington DC have a reciprocity agreement. You fill out all your taxes based on where you live not where you work.

I have worked for a company headquartered in Maryland, but in the DC office, while living in Virginia. The only tax form was for Virginia. The state W-4 was for Virginia.

If you had your employer send your state income tax withholding to the wrong state, you will have to file a form with that state to get that money back.

I was never in the situation where I had rental income in one state while living in the other, so I cant answer how that would change things.

Answer (score 5):

You probably do. I don't know what having rental property has to do with anything, what's important is whether you have income in the State. You're a resident of Maryland, so you need to report your worldwide income on your Maryland State tax return. But you earn income in Virginia, so that State has the right to tax you first. As such you file a non-resident return in Virginia and report (and pay the tax on) your Virginia income. You can probably deduct that from your Maryland taxes, as many neighboring States have reciprocity agreements, but verify that.

Comment: A +1 answer. And still is, for the generic headline question. mhoran's answer specifically clarified for this state combo.